# Power BI: Publishing a new version on a workspace, does it update or replace the previous one?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a question basically about [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI) on Power BI.
If I publish a local Power BI file onto Power BI Service: company workplace.
And I've applied row level security, hidden page for some people, etc.

And later on I decide to add a new report page or update features.
When I publish the new one, does it replace the old one while preserving my security setting?
Or do I need to perhaps recreate the security setting?

I have not tried publishing onto shared workplace yet.